# jenkins package web project that overlay dependency a war

Tags: maven, jenkins, dependencies, package, overlay

I have a maven web project which dependency a war package through overlays.then I want use jenkins to build and package this project,but jenkins throw a error "Error unpacking file *.war" "*.war archive is not a ZIP archive" .who could help me, what I should do?

Comment: Why would you like to use jenkins for packaging cause you wrote you already done that via Maven (overlays)..?

Comment: because i must integrate the thirdparty web war package for our project

Comment: Why not using overlay for that as well? You should of course transfer that war into your repository manager..

Comment: yes,i have dependency that war through maven pom, and that war had existed in our maven repository